# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when opening up service configuration for edit

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3, and just installed the latest Azure SDK 2.4. When I attempt to open up up the UI for editing the Service Configuration for a Web Role or Worker Role project in visual studio 2013, I get a blank popup window and a windows security login prompt for our local Active Directory server. If I cancel out of this window or log in with my credentials, Visual Studio immediately crashes. [Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCO1a.png)
Looking at the windows event logs, I see two errors:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AggregateException
Stack:
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__4(System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

And

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.30723.0, time stamp: 0x53cf6f00
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17055, time stamp: 0x532943a3
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00011d4d
Faulting process id: 0x1b74
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfc3a88ba59f99
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dd94972d-2fa1-11e4-be79-8851fb6ba868
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This happens on a new blank project. I have no idea why the service configuration UI would need to connect up to our AD server; the project I'm working on won't have AD integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**Updated Sept. 30th, 2014**

The problem apparently stems from the authentication process.

If you are using your company email as username on Azure, the inherent domain name will cause the authentication method to redirect you to your company's Active Directory.

The problem can be solved by choosing a different email as username on Azure.

The problem can also be replicated by setting up a website with authentication using Azure Active Directory. During login through Azure AD, the exact moment you enter the domain name in your username, the login screen redirects you from the Azure AD to the AD at sts.[email domain name] - and consequently, the login fails. Using a different username the Azure AD authentication works flawlessly.

---

I had the exact same problem and did *not* find a good solution.

Manually downgrading the project to **Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.3** by changing references and manually editing diverse config- and project files did not solve the problem, still crashing.

I ended up uninstalling all **Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.4** components and created a new project, migrating all code from the problematic project. This new project works without IDE crashes.

*Note!
Installing **Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.4** anew does not reintroduce the IDE crash issue on the existing 2.3 project. However, even new cloud projects created on this freshly installed v2.4 still exhibits the IDE crash issue.*